# String manipulation in XSLT functions

Tags: xml, json, xslt

I have a XML data which I am converting in to JSON data using XSLT. In that XML i have one of the tag as shown below.

`<title>[TLK-23805] config.manage.property default will not work </title>`

I want to chop off  `[TLK-23805]`. The title tag will always be in the format shown above just the value inside it changes as data is dynamic. How should I do this using XSLT? I really need some idea how to do this as I searched a bit but couldn't find a suitable solution. Here is my XSLT script[image]

Comment: Next time could you paste your code as text? That will allow improvements in formatting, making it easier to read; and searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to be more precise about what you want to trim.  I'm sure it is not `[TLK-23805]` all the time.  Assuming you want to trim up to the ending `]`,

```
fn:substring-after
```

should be sufficient.  For more details, see Chapter 7 in the [W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/)

Comment: Yes i want to Trim up to ending ]